# Loop if with find statement not working

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have this "case" loop in the end of a sh script that should work as cleaner, but it doesn't, below the code that i'm using

```
TARGET_DMPDIR=`sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" <<EOF
    SET PAGESIZE 0
    SET LINESIZE 200
    SET HEADING OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET TRIMSPOOL ON
    SET FEED OFF
    SET VERIFY OFF
    select directory_path from dba_directories where directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR';
    exit;
EOF`
DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"` 
COMPRESSED_EXPORTFILE="${ORACLE_SID}_${DATE}.dmp" (before the export)
COMPRESSED_EXPORTFILE=${COMPRESSED_EXPORTFILE}.Z (after export)



    case "$ORACLE_SID" in
        LIVE) t=6 ;;
        *)    t=1 ;;
    esac

    find "$TARGET_DMPDIR" -type f '(' -name "$COMPRESSED_EXPORTFILE" -o -name "exp_*_$ORACLE_SID.log" ')' \
        -mtime +"$t" -print -exec rm {} \;
```

This what i have in my TARGET_DMPDIR:

```
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba       814252 Mar  7 21:08 LIVE_20180307-210159.dmp.Z
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba       819516 Mar  8 21:09 LIVE_20180308-210202.dmp.Z
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba       814493 Mar  9 21:08 LIVE_20180309-210158.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba         3167 Mar  9 21:08 exp_20180309_LIVE.log
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba       820402 Mar 10 21:08 LIVE_20180310-210157.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba         3169 Mar 10 21:08 exp_20180310_LIVE.log
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba       822035 Mar 11 21:08 LIVE_20180311-210158.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba         3169 Mar 11 21:08 exp_20180311_LIVE.log
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba       814219 Mar 12 21:08 LIVE_20180312-210157.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba         3169 Mar 12 21:08 exp_20180312_LIVE.log
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba      21725862211 Mar 14 00:13 LIVE_20180313-212553.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba       172259 Mar 14 00:13 exp_20180313_LIVE.log
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba      21751392439 Mar 15 00:13 LIVE_20180314-212558.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba       172259 Mar 15 00:13 exp_20180314_LIVE.log
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba      21773328817 Mar 16 00:14 LIVE_20180315-212518.dmp.Z
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba       172259 Mar 16 00:14 exp_20180315_LIVE.log
```

Comment: do you mean for find and rm? it's just to be sure to pick them up when the script runs

Comment: Some finds have an -delete switch (gnu find). I don't see a `fi`. Btw.: There is no such thing as an if-loop, it's a branch.

Comment: Are you able to give examples of files that _ought_ to have been deleted, but weren't?

Comment: Dump file: LIVE_20180313-212553.dmp.Z
Log file: exp_20180313_LIVE.log

Comment: And the "last modification timestamp" (the `mtime`) of those files are more than six days in the past? You may check this with `stat filename`.

Comment: Yes, the oldest file has been created the 7th March. But also, i can see for the other ORACLE_SIDs, it doesn't keep just the last one, but all of them

Comment: @Kusalananda any suggestion about why is not deleting the oldest files? Thanks

Comment: @FaMontyN2 You are either looking at the wrong files or at the wrong timestamps. We don't know what your `$TARGET_DMPDIR` is or what's in it and we don't know what the `mtime` timestamp is on the files you say should be deleted. You say it's the "7th March", but it would be better to show all of this in the question (with the exact output of `stat` on those files).

Comment: @Kusalananda i added how i declare my variables that you highlighted and also what i have in the direcotory. I'm sorry but STAT is not installed in this server. As you may can notice, some old logs are missing, but the dump are still there. Am i missing something?

Comment: If you use `set -x` at the start of the script it will produce tracing output when run. It will show the values used for all variables and exactly what commands are executed. Run it like that and verify that the involved variables have the values that you expect them to have.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for helping. I've ran it with **set -x** (i knew what it does by the way) and actually is looking for the right files in the right location:

`+ compress -f /backup/flash_recovery_area/datapump/live/LIVE_20180316-105907.dmp

+ export COMPRESSED_EXPORTFILE=LIVE_20180316-105907.dmp.Z

+ find /backup/flash_recovery_area/datapump/live -type f ( -name LIVE_20180316-105907.dmp.Z -o -name exp_*_LIVE.log ) -m
time +6 -print -exec rm {} ;`

Comment: And the `exp_20180309_LIVE.log` file is still there?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, it is the oldest log in the directory

Comment: Is the directory mounted on/as a Windows filesystem. The file listing that you show is not a standard `ls -l` output, is it take from another operating system?

Comment: No, it's solaris machine. Sorry, i just cut the rest earlier, please check it now

Comment: I'm giving up on this for the time being. I'm almost certain it's something simple that is just being overlooked. Try _removing_ the `-exec rm` bit and reduce the `6` to `5` or `4` or even `1` just to see if it prints something.

Comment: ok @Kusalananda, no problem. i undertand that is not easy but i really appreciate your support. I'll try to "play" with the script to see if something change. and i'm sure too is something simple that i'm missing. Thanks